# Creating a Restricted User Account

Tags: users, settings, restricted-access

I'm currently trying to build an ubuntu 20.04 image where the user account is pretty locked down. I dont want the user to be able to change any settings or use terminal or anything else. They are only given one app to use that lives on their desktop and thats all they can use. How can i go about creating a user account like this?

Comment: Seems like you are trying to create a kiosk?

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/secure-ubuntu-kiosk#1-moved will get you started

Comment: Kiosk mode might work...it'll be for pcoip software client.